# About Nvidia visual profiler, what does warp efficiency mean?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, profiler

I mean the exact definition, why the Nvidia profiler always tell me that my codes have very poor warp efficiency due to branch divegence within a warp in SM3.5?

My code have avoided branch within a warp as much as possible and if my code is built with SM 2.0, the nvidia profiler will tell me that the warp efficiency is close to 100%.

But on the same card, if my code were built with SM 3.5, then all of a sudden the warp efficiency will drop to 35%-40%, which is incredible low efficiency.

And the instructions issue pattern are: dual issues is about 50% of the cases of single issue per warp.

All the rest are fine, so can somebody tell me what is the exactly definition about warp efficiency, aint they suppose to mean the amount of active threads within a warp that run concurrently at any given time divided by the warp size?

So why my codes, when built with different SM versions,  has such a significantly different reported warp efficiency (~35% warp efficiency with SM3.5, and close to 100% warp efficiency with SM2.0)on the same nvidia gpu?

Comment: You've already asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531524/how-could-nvidia-cuda-visual-profiler-tell-me-this) recently, correct?  What GPU are you executing the code on?  You might generate the ptx code and see what the compiler is spitting out that is so different.  You might also post a simple, compilable reproducer, if you can create one.

Comment: @yes, I have, but nobody answers, I have modify all the rest part of my codes such that the profiler tell me all the rest are alright, just this outstanding problem, so now I want to figure out whats wrong with that, the GPU that run this code is gk110.

Comment: If you provide a reproducible with your question you are much more likely to get an answer. The metric warp execution efficiency is defined as "Ratio of the average active threads per warp to the maximum number of threads per warp supported on a multiprocessor." I'm not sure if by "warp efficiency" if you are referring to this metric or a different metric.  This will be low if you launch a non-multiple of 32 threads, if threads in a warp exit early, or if you have a divergent thread execution. It only takes a single divergent branch for this number to be very low.

Answer (score 1):

For a specific kernel that is reported as having low warp efficiency you can use the "Divergent Branch" analysis to see what specific branches (if any) are causing divergence and thereby contributing to low warp efficiency.